# regular expression for matching measurements

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to pick measurements out of a string in my treetop grammar.

I'm trying to simply get all the different ways of saying 'inch', so my regular expression is

```
in(|ches|ch|)?i
```

what I thought the above was saying was 
starts with 'in',may have either 'ches' or 'ch', and do a case-insensitive search

I've been trying to get this to work in http://rubular.com/, but haven't been able to.

Am I completely missing how regular expressions are supposed to work? I've tried all sorts of combinations with quotes, square braces, etc. etc. but no luck.

Comment: You have an extra 'i' at the end of your regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many `|`'s; `|` means or, so you match `in` followed by `the empty string` or `ches` or `ch` or `the empty string`. Then you follow it with i, so your regex will match `ini`, `inchi`, or `inchesi`.

You could use:

```
in(ches|ch)?
```

If you don't want to match `in` by itself then you could also use: `inch(es)?`

Also I believe your `i` is meant to mean case-insensitive, not match the character i. In whch case you should put it in the second box on rubular. After the `/`

Answer (score 2):

you can simplify that quite a bit

```
inch(es)?
```

Should be enough.

Comment: in the case of `inches` this will only match `inch`

Comment: @Pablo Not true, it is greedy by default. It would only match inch if he had written `inch(es)??`, however, his regex won't match `in` by itself which I'm pretty sure the OP desired.

Comment: You could express inches like `6 in`, and your regex wouldn't count for that interpretation.

Comment: @PaulPRO indeed, you're right. It's in the `in(ch|ches)` that the first match is chosen, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the pipe character in the middle between each of your alternations:

```
in(ches|ch)?i
```

Also, you might factor out the "ch":

```
inch(es)?
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following, assuming the valid possibilities are "in", "inch", and "inches".

```
in(ch(es)?)?
```

Answer (score 0):

| is a binary operator, it needs a value at both sides. If you want to deal with "in", then you should use the ? operator (zero or one ocurrences)

```
in(ch|ches)?
```

or even

```
in(ch(es)?)?
```

Anyway for this kind of expression, I would favor the ease of read of

```
in|inch|inches
```

Answer (score 0):

### Regex

```
/in(ches|ch)?/i
```

### Rubular Example

http://rubular.com/r/taKbHiVqys

Answer (score 0):

Beside the other answers and the hint about | and option i.

Perhaps you need also a test of the characters in front. Just think to a phrase like *if it comes to the pinch, you find a measurement*

My 2nd regex checks for leading spaces or digits. Perhaps you need also a \A for the begin of a string.

```
[
  'if it comes to the pinch, you find a measurement',
  '5 inches',
  '5inches',
].each{|phrase|
  puts phrase
    [ 
      /in(ch|ches)/,
      /(\s|\d)in(ch|ches)/
    ].each{|regex|
      if phrase =~ regex
        puts "-> hits #{regex}"
      end
  }
}
```